# Set pdf viewer in IWebBrowser2 when it is displaying pdf file(C++)

Tags: pdf, mfc, registry, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

I create a MFC project with `IWebBrowser2` to display the pdf file.
In my MFC project, it has a dialog and the dialog has a web browser activeX control. This activeX control is associate with `IWebBrowser2`.

By using the `Navigate` API from `IWebBrowser2`, it can display the local pdf on my disk, but when it is showing the pdf, it is using my default pdf viewer, Adobe.

Here is the problem, we installed two pdf viewers, one is Adobe and another one is FoxitReader, Adobe is my default pdf viewer app. I hope that when my MFC project displaying pdf in its dialog, it can use FoxitReader in its dialog, it shouldn't affect user's default settings outside of my project.

For example ( pesudo code):

```
IWebBrowser2Ptr->Navigate("the url of my local pdf");
IWebBrowser2Ptr->SetDocumentSettings("Using FoxitReader");
```

Comment: `IWebBrowser` is not an application launcher. If you want to launch the default application for any given file type, call `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: @IInspectable But IWebBrowser2 has an API called "Navigate" and can be used to display the local pdf. IWebBrowser is an active X control in my MFC dialog, if I launch default application for pdf file, how could I make it displayed in my MFC dialog ?

Comment: You can't. And you cannot change the behavior of your `IWebBrowser` ActiveX control. Its job is to render HTML (or whichever other file types it supports, like PDF). It doesn't come with a separate PDF renderer, that can be exchanged for another implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable I updated my question to make it clear. So what you mean is, iwebbrowser will always use the defined default PDF viewer app to display the pdf in its dialog ? If it is correct, may I embed a pdf into a html file, and set the default pdf viewer in the html file and display the html file in the iwebbrowser ?